# How can I increase the resolution of a 3d plot in Sage to see all the details of the noodle?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, parametric, sagemath

I want to plot my noodle with a high resolution to see all the details. How can I achieve this with Sage?

Here is my parametric, piecewise function:

```
var('u,v')
a(u,v)=-7*sin(((u-100)/(100))*pi)^2+0.2*sin(((3*u-300)/(10))*pi)
b(u,v)=-8*cos(((u-100)/(100))*pi)+0.2*cos(((3*u-300)/(10))*pi)
c(u,v)=-12*cos(((u-100)/(100))*pi)+15*sin(((v-20)/(40))*pi)
def x(u,v):
    if u < 100:
        return 7*sin((u/100)*pi)^2+0.15*sin((3*u/10)*pi)
    else:
        return a(u,v)
def y(u,v):
    if u < 100:
        return 8*cos((u/100)*pi)+0.15*cos((3*u/10)*pi)
    else:
        return b(u,v)
def z(u,v):
    if u < 100:
        return 12*cos((u/100)*pi)+15*sin(((v-20)/40)*pi)
    else:
        return c(u,v)
parametric_plot3d([x,y,z], (u, 0, 200), (v, 0, 40), frame=False)
```

Maybe you want to try it [here](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/). The result looks like this:

[image: sage_plot]
[image: sage_plot2]

Actually there should be more, wavy details of this Pennoni Rigati noodle.
[moodle http://www.pastificiofaella.com/eng/prod/pennoni_rigati.jpg](http://www.pastificiofaella.com/eng/prod/pennoni_rigati.jpg)

How can I get a better result? Maybe it's also possible to get a scatter result, but how?

Comment: This question is better suited for the SAGE "stackexchange" http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the option plot_points. See examples at http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/parametric_plot3d.html.